# How do I create a java library that is dependent upon another library?

Tags: java

I am creating my own java library to help me when creating games. This library is just for personal development. However, some of the commands within the library are dependent upon slick2D which is dependent upon lwjgl.

***Question:*** How do I develop this library without including the other libraries inside that package?

P.S: I understand that when ever I use this library that I will have to use Slick2D and lwjgl with it and I am ok with it.

Comment: What do you mean with "that package"? (The Java `package` your source files reside in? The JAR that you're going to distribute? Or something else?)

Comment: Please do not use code markup to highlight your question, instead you can use BOLD or ITALIC text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You develop it as you normally would. Just include the library into your CLASSPATH so you can test it. Once is ready, you just build the jar and that's it, you can start distribute your library. When you distribute your library, the project that uses it, has to include into their CLASSPATH your library and their dependencies as well.

So, all you have to do is let know the developers that will use your library, what are its dependencies and their versions. That's it.

For example:

You develop library.jar that depends on dep1.jar and dep2.jar

When you are developing, you need to include your dependencies in your CLASSPATH, so you can test, right?

But when you build library.jar, it will not include dep1.jar and dep2.jar.

Meaning that if I'm going to use your library, I will have to include library.jar, dep1.jar, and dep2.jar into my CLASSPATH.

The ClassLoader will load the libraries classes and when your classes make use of the dep1.jar/dep2.jar classes, they all will be loaded.

Answer (score 4):

I would advise using **maven** as build infrastructure. There one can define dependencies and version management. Look into your IDE.

Comment: Agreed. Maven is the way to go.